# Moving qubits in surface code: I don't get why it works

Tags: error-correction, stabilizer-code, surface-code

I am reading [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1208.0928), in particular the part where they explain it is possible to move qubits in the surface code.

I don't understand the procedure that allows to move logical qubits on the array. Below is the picture and the caption below it.

[image]

```
FIG. 17. (Color online) Process for moving a Z-cut logical
qubit hole vertically down by one cell in the 2D array. (a)
Logical qubit with $X_L = X_1X_2X_3$ and $Z_L = Z_3Z_4Z_5Z_6$. (b)
We extend the ZˆL operator by multiplying it by the Zˆ stabilizer just below the lower qubit hole: $Z^e_L = (Z_6Z_7Z_8Z_9)Z^L =
Z_3Z_4Z_5Z_7Z_8Z_9$. We next turn off this Z stabilizer, and also
turn the surrounding four-terminal X stabilizers into three terminal stabilizers, leaving data qubit 6 without any stabilizer measurements. We perform an X measurement of
data qubit 6 (using either an idle measure-Z qubit, or directly measuring the data qubit, as shown). (c) We define the extended operator $X′_L$ by multiplying $X^L$ by $X^6$:
$X′_L = X_6X_L = X_1X_2X_3X_6$. We now turn on the Z stabilizer
just above qubit 6; we wait d surface code cycles in order to
properly establish the value of this stabilizer. We define $Z′_L$
as the product of this Z stabilizer and $Z^e_L: Z′_L = Z_6Z_7Z_8Z_9$.
```

What I don't understand is: how can we be sure that the logical qubit will be preserve through this transformation?

I am not even sure to know how to tackle this question in a "smart" way (i.e in the pure stabilizer formalism).

At least one necessary condition I found is to check if all the operations I am doing between **a)** and **c)** are commuting with both $Z_L^e \equiv Z_3 Z_4 Z_5 Z_6 Z_7 Z_8 Z_9$ which defines my logical $Z$ operator for all the steps (on **a)** it is equal to $Z_3 Z_4 Z_5 Z_6$ up to a sign, and on **c)** to $Z_6 Z_7 Z_8 Z_9$ up to a sign). It seems to be the case. I should also check if all those operations are commuting with the logical $X$ but as its definition "changes" between **a)** and **c)** I am confused.

My question in short:

1. How to show properly that the logical information is preserved during those operations
2. How to show that we keep the same level of protection by doing this

Answer (score 1):

I would like to provide an intuitive understanding about why this process is reasonable. When we extend the defect as shown in (b), three stabilizers are affected, (i) the four-terminal Z stabilizer Z_6789 is turned off (ii) the two four-terminal X stabilizers around data qubit 6 become three-terminal stabilizers. The X measurement of data qubit 6 allows us to recover the information of those two four-terminal X stabilizers (by simply multiplying the outcome of X_6 with that of the three-terminal X stabilizers). So effectively, we only lose the information of the Z stabilizer Z_6789 while gaining an additional information of X_6. The disabled Z stabilizer Z_6789 introduces an extra degree of freedom beyond the logical qubit. But this degree of freedom is then eliminated by the X-measurement on data qubit 6, restoring us to the degree of freedom of a single logical qubit.